# Hierarchical Regression analysis: predictor sig, block non sig

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares

I ran hierarchical regression.

Block 1
and Block 2.

add block 2 does not significantly improve model fit (p>0.05).

However, one predictor in block 2 is sig. (p<0.05)

In this case, can I report the full model (with block 2) and interpret sig predictor in block 2 as significant predictor?